# Resize Images in Canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-canvas

I'm displaying a bitmap on Inside the ImageView and using the Canvas .

ImageView : it display the whole image not matter how large the image, it compress bitmap within the width/height of Imageview.

Canvas : canvas draw the bitmap but if the bitmap is larger it goes out of screen.

How to same behavior for bitmap on canvas like Imageview display.?

Comment: Didn't get this line: How to same behavior for bitmap on canvas like Imageview display.?

Comment: If i take a large Bitmap use setImageBitmap for ImageView , here usser can see the whole Image similarly for the same bitmap while draw it on canvas some of it's portion goes out of screen.

Comment: "it compress bitmap within the width/height of Imageview."

-- You mean it resizes the bitmap right ?

Comment: "it compress bitmap within the width/height of Imageview." Exactly i need the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize a bitmap 
take a look at [`drawBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) method in the canvas, Each overloaded method allows you to specify a size. For example here is the signature of one of the methods

`public void drawBitmap (int[] colors, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean hasAlpha, Paint paint)`

It allows you specify the width and height .

Or

Use [`public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) and

use [`public void setScale (float sx, float sy)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setScale%28float,%20float%29) to resize

Use this to re-size the image based on your needs

Comment: it will make it harder for me implement the zoom features in it without using the matrix.Since above function doesn't use Matrix to display the bitmap.

Comment: Then use this method `public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)` and resize in the Matrix using `public void setScale (float sx, float sy)` method of the Matrix